# ssh-copy-id gives Permission Denied (publickey, pasword) on Kali root user

Tags: ssh, permissions, kali-linux, ssh-keys

I have installed a Kali Linux recently as a VirtualBox VM and I was trying to set it up to have ssh access from my local computer.

I changed `PasswordAuthentication` parameter to `yes` on Kali to use `ssh-copy-id` to copy my publickey. But when I run `ssh-copy-id root@IP` and after entering root password (which I provided while installation), it gives me `Permission denied (publickey,password)`.

On Kali's `/var/log/auth.log` I can see `Failed Password` log from my attempts, but I'm sure it's correct (I logged in to Kali using it).

I tried changing root password of Kali using `passwd root` and it didn't ask me for my current password, however, it says `passwd: password updated successfully`. But this can be seen in `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password changed for root
gkr-pam: couldn't update the login keyring password: no old password was entered
```

I don't know what it has changed, but doing `ssh-copy-id` didn't work again. I also didn't manage to copy my publickey manually, because of some clipboard problems.

If I create another user than `root`, `ssh-copy-id` works. But what if someone really wants to ssh directly to root? Why it says my password is wrong? Is the password I use when logging in different with what I use when running superuser commands? Where can I change root password?

**UPDATE:** Using that new created user, I copied `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Now I can ssh directly to root. But that Permission Denied error remained a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

**Did you enable root login over ssh?**

To do that add following line to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in authentication block.

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

When using SSH Keys, you can set the `PermitRootLogin` value to `without-password` instead of `yes`.

Finally restart the SSH server.